# Converting letters to dashes

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I have been asked to make a game at work where I have to change the letters to dashes. I have been told to use a multi dimensional array but I get the full word out of a text file. This is the code i have so far

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter file path:");
            string filePath= Console.ReadLine();

            // read all the lines from the file
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(readFilePath);

            // get a random number between 0 and less than the number of lines in the file
            Random rand = new Random();
            int chosenLineIndex = rand.Next(lines.Length);

            // choose the line at the line number
            string chosenLine = lines[chosenLineIndex];

            // write the line to the Console
            Console.WriteLine(chosenLine);

            // make an array containing the only the chosen line
            string[] chosenLines = new string[] { chosenLine };
```

So does anyone know how to write the letters separately to the array instead of the full word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you an array that contains each character separately as a `string`.

```
string[] chosenLines =  chosenLine.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
```

You can also use a `char[]` array instead.Then you won't need `Select`, you can just use [String.ToCharArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are looking for [String.ToCharArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x(v=vs.110).aspx)